# Can one ensure that certain people subscribe to a particular card in Trello?

Tags: trello-cards, trello-lists

If not, one has to add a `FYI` or a `cc` to a list of people in each message.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to subscribe others to cards.

Comment: Can you add more content to this answer? The OP asked how he could message people to go to the specific card to subscribe to it if subscribing them to the card didn't work.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'll need to ask the other person to subscribe to that particular card. Thanks for your response!